# C show (print) in main function , while values returned in custom one

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

This program needs to make the user input two numbers : m and n in the main function. Then it needs to calculate in a custom function all the factors of n starting with m. Then it needs to show/print those factors in the main function.

The important thing is : you can't print the factors from the custom function, only from the main function. Also no global variables.

My program only returns the first factor (it should be input 1(m), 18(n) = 1,2,3,6,9,18)

I also have the problem with the for() in the main function, i don't know what i should use as the limit, as it returns many times more than the number of factors a number has.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int toti_factori(int x,int y);

main(){
    int m,n,i;
    printf("intro m si n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",toti_factori(m,n));
    }


}

int toti_factori(int x,int y){
static int i=1;
int t=0;
    for(i=1;i<=y;i++){

        if(y%i==0){
            if(i>=x){
            return i;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

1. Create a `struct` that can hold all the factors.
2. Return an object of the `struct` from `toti_factori`.
3. Use the contents of the `struct` as you see fit.

Here's a working program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Factors
{
   size_t size;
   int* data;
} Factors;

Factors toti_factori(int x, int y);

int main(){
   int m, n, i;

   printf("intro m si n: ");
   scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

   // Get all the factors in one call.
   Factors factors = toti_factori(m, n);

   // Print the factors.
   for ( i = 0; i < factors.size; ++i)
   {
      printf("%d ",factors.data[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   // Deallocate memory before program ends.
   free(factors.data);

   return 0;
}

Factors toti_factori(int m, int n){
   int count = 0;
   int index = 0;
   Factors factors;

   int i = 0;

   // Find out the number of factors.
   for ( i = m; i <= n; ++i)
   {
      if ( n%i == 0)
      {
         ++count;
      }
   }

   // Allocate memory for the factors.
   factors.size = count;
   factors.data = malloc(count*sizeof(*factors.data));

   // Gather the factors.
   for ( i = m; i <= n; ++i)
   {
      if ( n%i == 0)
      {
         factors.data[index] = i;
         ++index;
      }
   }

   return factors;
}
```

**A solution that doesn't use a `struct`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int toti_factori(int x, int y);

int main(){
   int m, n, i;

   printf("intro m si n: ");
   scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

   // Print the factors.
   for ( i = m; i < n; ++i)
   {
      // Get the next factor and store it in i.
      i = toti_factori(i, n);
      printf("%d ", i);
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}

int toti_factori(int m, int n){

   int i = 0;
   for ( i = m; i <= n; ++i)
   {
      if ( n%i == 0)
      {
         return i;
      }
   }
   return i;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, i can't use arrays or structs. A friend did this problem by adding as a parameter the last factor. I didn't understand what he meant though.

Comment: How can i return the factors one by one ( 1 then 2 then 3) in my program?

Answer (score 0):

It only returns an int, not an int array. I the first loop in the second for(), it returns one value and skips the function. Try changing the return type to int[]. You cant print anything because the method finishes before the print method 
Edit:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int toti_factori(int x,int y);

main(){
    int m,n,i;
    printf("intro m si n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",toti_factori(m,n));
    }


}

int toti_factori(int x,int y){
static int i=1;
int t=0;
    for(int a=0;i<=y;i++){ //a does nothing

        if(y%i==0){
            if(i>=x){
            return i;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i want it to successivly return 1 then return 2 ,3 etc. (the factors of 18 starting with 1) - also can't use arrays

Comment: @Stack_token So modify your function such that it will receive additional parameter indicating the index of the factor, and then iterate it in the main.

Comment: You should use a global variable that haves the count number (like i in the second for method).

Comment: Your problem is that you do i = 1every time the function is called

Comment: How do i fix that? i tried using static, dosen't work

Comment: If you initialize the int i every time the function is called, you are doing it wrong. See my edit answer